# Find if text exist inside a nested Div, if yes print out the whole string, Selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

i'm very new to selenium(3.141.0) and python3, and i got a problem that couldn't figure it out.

The html looks similar to this

```
<div class='a'>
   <div>
     <p><b>ABC</b></p>
     <p><b>ABC#123</b></p>
     <p><b>XYZ</b></p> 
   <div>
</div>
```

I want selenium to find if # exist inside that div, (can not target the paragraph only element because sometime the text i want to extract is inside different element BUT it's always inside that `<div class='a'>`) If # exist => print the whole `<p><b>ABC#123</b></p>` (or sometime `<div>ABC#123<div>` )

Comment: //div[@class='a']//b[contains(text(),'#') should look a b  tag that has # in it's text.

Answer (score 0):

To find an element with contained text, you must use an XPath. From what you are describing, it looks like you want the locator

```
//div[@class='a']//*[contains(text(),'#')]
^ a DIV with class 'a'
                 ^ that has a descendant element that contains the text '#' within itself or a descendant
```

The code would look something like

```
for e in driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='a']//*[contains(text(),'#')]"):
    print(e.get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

and it will print all instances of `<b>ABC#123</b>`, `<div>ABC#123</div>`, or `<p>ABC#123</p>`, whichever exists

Comment: The problem is ABC#123 sometime inside a <div> instead of <p> and //p[contains(.,'#') not working all the time, but i learned something new in your answer about outerHTML thank you so much.

Comment: @Kan Sorry, I saw your second example and I thought I had it accounted for but I misread it. I've updated the locator and code.